# Internal server error после установки ActionFilter

Tags: c#, ninject, webapi

Пишу фильтр-логгер запросов. MVC WebAPI+NInject.

Класс фильтра:

```
public class LogFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private LogInfo Info { get; set; } = new LogInfo();

    public LogFilter(IMobileDal dal)
    {
        Dal = dal;
    }

    private IMobileDal Dal { get; }
    public bool AllowMultiple { get; } = true;

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        Info.Action = actionContext.Request.Method.Method;
        Info.Url = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
        Info.DateBegin = DateTime.Now;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
        {
            sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            Info.Request = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var result = await continuation();
        Info.DateEnd = DateTime.Now;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
        {
            sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            Info.Response = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Info.Status = (int)result.StatusCode;
        Dal.AddLogRecord(Info);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Привязка в NInject:

```
    this.BindHttpFilter<LogFilter>(FilterScope.Action)
        .WithConstructorArgument("dal", context => context.Kernel.Get<IMobileDal>());
```

Запросы отрабатывают, записи сваливаются в базу, я вижу ожидаемый результат - но на выходе получаю 500 Internal server error. При том, что в `result` - вполне себе 200.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: трассировка стека? Как может быть 500, если 200?

Comment: @tym32167 так и я не понимаю, как может быть 500. в дебаге в call stack ничего, в `return result` в резалте лежит 200, ОК.

Comment: так оберните содержимое `ExecuteActionFilterAsync` в try/catch и ловите в дебаге эксепшон

Comment: @tym32167 так в том и дело - не выбрасывает он исключений. Я его в дебаге прошёл от и до - пусто. отрабатывает `return result` - и клиент получает 500. Обернул в try/catch - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: не знаю, связано оно или нет, то я [чутка погуглил](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/11/asynchronous-action-filters-asp-net-web-api/) и там зачем то результат сначала оборачивают в `HttpActionExecutedContext`, а потом возвращают `return executedContext.Response;`

Comment: Тоже не сработало. Подозреваю NInject...

Comment: Может быть, это я уже не подскажу :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By design the body content in ASP.NET Web API is treated as forward-only stream that can be read only once.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494067/read-httpcontent-in-webapi-controller/12494758#12494758

И после того, как я прочитал результат - клиент его получить уже не смог.